# Google Play Alpha Testers Link not working

Tags: android, google-play

Have a current Release V1 for all users to download and use.
Uploaded a new APK for alpha testers only.
It says share https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.TheGSX.android with my alpha testers
But the page gives 404

Comment: Did you do it just now? It may take a while to get published.

Comment: Is this the right link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TheGSX.android?

Comment: I published a new version for aplha on Dec 7th in Alpha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it does take a while to get uploaded, from my experience, you need to give permissions too and not just distribute the link. This can be done by creating Google Groups or Google+ Communities and adding these after clicking "Manage list of testers" in the Alpha Testing tab in APK section. To give individual permissions click the cog on the left and add email addresses there.

Comment: I published it on Dec 7th and it says share this link https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.TheGSX.android which I tried from my wife's android phone and it would not even load the page. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add her gmail address under settings as mentioned?

Comment: Yes and still no luck

Comment: Did you try adding her to a group or community and adding that? If so I have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: So it finally worked. Thank you for your patience and guidance